# Find the slope of the tangent line of $f(x)=x^3+\sqrt{x}+(2x)^{−1}$ at $x=1$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Find the slope of the tangent line of $f(x)=x^3+\sqrt{x}+(2x)^{−1}$ at $x=1$.

I use the power rule which gives me

$$3x^2+1/2x^{-1/2}-2x^{-2}$$

And when I plug it's not right, why?

Answer (score 4):

The derivative of $f(x)=(2x)^{-1}$ is not $-2x^{-2}$ or $(-2x)^{-2}$; it is $\,-\frac{1}{2}x^{-2}$.